# Fatal error: Class ConnectionWrapper not found in ConnectionFactory.php

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

I am a newbie with `Propel ORM`. I installed the ORM to my server. I made all of the configurations. My model classes are generated and I can create objects and call their specific methods.

However when I try to call the `save` method of the `propel` class, it prints a **fatal error** to the apache log. You can see the log error below :

> Fatal error:  Class ConnectionWrapper not found in
>   ConnectionFactory.php on line 46

Here is my `composer.php` file which generates `autoload.php` file :

```
{
  "require": {
    "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev",
    "slim/slim": "2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["generated-classes/"]
   }
}
```

Here is my `test_service.php` file which I call the `propel methods`.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'generated-conf/config.php';
echo "ENTERED"."\n";


$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
echo $date."\n";

$customer = new Customer();
$customer->setName("Jason");
$customer->setSurname("Statham");
$customer->setType(2);
$customer->setEmail("jasonstatham@gmail.com");
$customer->setGender("Male");
$customer->setPassword("123");
$customer->setSignupDate($date);



echo $customer->getName()."\n";
echo $customer->getSurname()."\n";
echo $customer->getType()."\n";
echo $customer->getEmail()."\n";
echo $customer->getGender()."\n";
echo $customer->getPassword()."\n";
echo date_format($customer->getSignupDate(), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$customer->save();

echo "EXIT"."\n";

?>
```

In the above code, `get` and `set` methods of `Propel class` works with no problem. However when it comes to

```
$customer->save();
```

The apache prints the error to the log.
Here is the response to the request :

```
ENTERED
1970-01-01 02:00:00
Jason
Statham
2
jasonstatham@gmail.com
Male
123
1970-01-01 02:00:00
```

What do I miss here? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you autoloading the classes? Troubleshooting is difficult without seeing your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem...

The problem is caused because of the propel.yaml file which includes the database information :

```
propel:
 database:
  connections:
      test:
          adapter: mysql
          classname: Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper
          dsn: "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test"
          user: admin
          password: admin
          attributes:
runtime:
  defaultConnection: test
  connections:
      - test
  generator:
  defaultConnection: test
  connections:
      - test
```

This is the problem solved file. At first I wrote the system path of the ConnectionWrapper class to the classname and it was the error. It takes the namespace relation of the ConnectionWrapper class. So when I changed it with namespace relation, the problem is solved.